# Difference between tokenlist and raw text in expl3

Tags: expl3, token-lists

How to split token list by any char, like a raw document text?

For example, i have a code to bold first word in macro argument. Macro is correctly works for direct using from code, like `\bfirst{word word word}`, but my macro can't separate words if i use token list variable.

My code:

```
% XeLaTeX Document
\documentclass[a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

    % Bold first word in macro argument
    \seq_new:N \l_mytest_bstring_seq
    \tl_new:N  \l_mytest_bfirst_tl

    \NewDocumentCommand{\bfirst}{ m }
    {
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mytest_bstring_seq { ~ } { #1 }
        \seq_pop_left:NN   \l_mytest_bstring_seq \l_mytest_bfirst_tl

        \textbf{\l_mytest_bfirst_tl} ~
        \seq_use:Nn \l_mytest_bstring_seq { ~ }
    }

    % TL can't be splitted?
    \tl_new:N  \l_test_example_tl
    \tl_set:Nn \l_test_example_tl {TL\ word~word\ word...}

    \NewDocumentCommand{\tlbfirst}{}
    {
        \par\bfirst{\l_test_example_tl}
        \par\bfirst{\tl_use:N \l_test_example_tl}
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \par\bfirst{Word word word...}
    \tlbfirst
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Difference between commands]

How to make same result for raw text and token list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good example showing why complex `expl3` code shouldn't be used in the body of `\NewDocumentCommand`; only initializations and general checks, but the bulk of the task should be deferred to an internal function.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

% Bold first word in macro argument
\seq_new:N \l_mytest_bstring_seq
\tl_new:N  \l_mytest_bfirst_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\bfirst}{ m }
 {
  \mytest_bfirst:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mytest_bfirst:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mytest_bstring_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN   \l_mytest_bstring_seq \l_mytest_bfirst_tl

  \textbf{\l_mytest_bfirst_tl} ~
  \seq_use:Nn \l_mytest_bstring_seq { ~ }
}
% generate a variant of \mytest_bfirst:n
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mytest_bfirst:n { V }

% TL can't be split?
\tl_new:N  \l_test_example_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_test_example_tl {TL\ word~word\ word}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tlbfirst}{}
 {
  \mytest_bfirst:V \l_test_example_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\bfirst{Word word word}

\tlbfirst
\end{document}
```

In this way, the second user level macro can be defined in terms of `\mytest_bfirst:V`.

[image]

Comment: I disagree with “expl3 code shouldn't be used in the body of `\NewDocumentCommand` except for passing control to an internal function”. It shouldn't be used when it shouldn't be used (like in this cases). But there are many times when the *interface* macro is not just passing an argument to an *internal* macro but rather do some checks and more that (in my opinion, shouldn't be inside an expl3 macro because it doesn't belong to that level). It's just that I think that sentence is not good as a general rule.

Comment: @Manuel I reworded the paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

You want an `x` variant to expand the argument before splitting

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
   \cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {Nnx}
    % Bold first word in macro argument
    \seq_new:N \l_mytest_bstring_seq
    \tl_new:N  \l_mytest_bfirst_tl

    \NewDocumentCommand{\bfirst}{ m }
    {
        \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_mytest_bstring_seq { ~ } { #1 }
        \seq_pop_left:NN   \l_mytest_bstring_seq \l_mytest_bfirst_tl

        \textbf{\l_mytest_bfirst_tl} ~
        \seq_use:Nn \l_mytest_bstring_seq { ~ }
    }

    % TL can't be splitted?
    \tl_new:N  \l_test_example_tl
    \tl_set:Nn \l_test_example_tl {TL\ word~word\ word...}

    \NewDocumentCommand{\tlbfirst}{}
    {
        \par\bfirst{\l_test_example_tl}
        \par\bfirst{\tl_use:N \l_test_example_tl}
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \par\bfirst{Word word word...}
    \tlbfirst
\end{document}
```

Note this splits on a space (`~`) not control spaces (`\`) so `TL\ Word` is a single word.

Comment: I disagree with this solution; it abuses `x` expansion.